# Data Generation Plan that concatenates two columns to form Email

Tags: concatenation, calculated-columns, data-generation

Using the Visual Studio Data Generation Plan, I have two columns, FirstName and Lastname, populated from a Data Bound Generator (referencing a database seeded with actual valid First and Last Names). I want to generate another column for email with the format @test.com.

For example:

> Fred, Smith => fsmith@test.com

Right now I am using a regular expression for email so it is just random and unrelated to the name. It would be great to find a way to reference other columns when generating data in another column, as I will be doing this everywhere in my database.